# Distributed Database

Tags: database, replication, merge-replication, database-deployment, distributed-database

I NEED YOUR HELP
ANY IDEA ANY SOLUTION

SCENARIO:
    An organization suppose Jason industries have its branches in different regions of country. In each branch there is a local database where they maintain their data locally. Suppose one branch in New York, one in Washington, one in Texas. 
There is a main database in the main branch of the organization. At the end of each week or month each branch submits their data to the main database. I can say that they synchronize there data in the end of week or month. Note that each branch has its local database where data is kept in disconnected mode from main database. Only at end of each week or month the whole data of every branch is submitted to the main database..
My question is that is it possible? If yes, what this concept is called? And where from can I get help on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you will have multiple branches (Subscribers) which will make changes offline and occasionally synchronize - this sounds like a good fit for [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This also includes the concept of data warehousing wherein you have to go through a series of steps before putting data from all branches into the main database.

A few steps are like:

- Discarding the bad data
- Discarding the occurrence of data if same is present more than once
- ...